# generate multi-normal data in R

Tags: r

I was trying to genrate multi-normal data in `R` using `mvrnorm`, however, I got errors as:

```
> epsiloni <- mvrnorm(n = 1, rep(0,8), diag(1), tol = 1e-6, empirical = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE)
Error in mvrnorm(n = 1, rep(0, 8), diag(1), tol = 1e-06, empirical = FALSE,  
: incompatible arguments
```

But it works fine for other expectation and variance, like

```
betai <- mvrnorm(n = 1, mu, D, tol = 1e-6, empirical = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE)
```

where `mu` and `D` are specified otherwise.

The only difference between these two are just the expectations and the variance, but I did not see anything wrong with the mean and variance in `epsiloni`, they are just multi-standard normal.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `diag(8)` rather than `daig(1)` . Since you have 8 means, you need an 8x8 variance matrix.

Comment: @MrFlick Ah... I made a stupid mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `Sigma` to `diag(1)`, which is a 1x1 matrix, is the problem. If you want an identity covariance matrix for an 8-dimensional vector, you need `diag(8)`.

```
mvrnorm(n = 1, rep(0, 8), diag(8))
# [1] -0.3554192  0.6051595  0.3926595  0.2752819  0.8610572  0.2679094 -1.3581420 -0.2814057
```